# Python find.line does not filter date string from text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large txt file of data trades, where I want to filter data as I read them into a panda dataframe.

I can't seem to get it to filter/obtain the data when the string is the date.

```
2017-07-28 09:39:04.442 Allocation: BUY 7.0 AZN @ 43.665, 
2017-07-28 09:39:07.724 Allocation: BUY 400.0 BT.A @ 3.022, 
2017-07-28 09:39:08.802 Allocation: BUY 604.0 PFC @ 4.442, 
2017-07-28 09:39:03.000 Allocation: SELL 1083 PFC @ 4.4432, 
2017-07-28 09:39:03.000 Allocation: SELL 2350 PCT @ 10.3807, 
2017-07-28 09:39:06.000 Allocation: SELL 2000 PFC @ 4.4565, 
2017-07-28 09:39:07.000 Allocation: BUY 3000 VOD @ 2.21219, 
2017-07-28 09:39:08.000 Allocation: SELL 2518 CLLN @ 0.5927,
```

My code is below : it works when the filter is something like 'BP', but not when it is '2017-07-28'.

```
# this is to load the text file into content
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

# this is to filter the lines in the data
events = []
for line in content:
    #if (line.find('Action') >0 and line.find('BP') > 0) : 
    if line.find('2017-07-28') > 0:    
        events.append(line.split(' '))

data = pd.DataFrame(events)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because each line is just a string, you can use `in` like this:

```
for line in content:
    if '2017-07-28' in line: 
        events.append(line.split(' '))
```

or using list comprehension

```
events = [ line.split(' ') for line in content if '2017-07-28' in line ]
```

Comment: nope... doesn't work ...... MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-b88eab77b885> in <module>()
      6 # this is to load the text file into content
      7 with open(file) as f:
----> 8     content = f.readlines()

Comment: that's completely unrelated to the question you're asking... your file is too large to read into memory

Comment: it looks like a 'memory error', but I generated a test file (of much smaller size) to check, and unfortunately, it had the same error

Comment: okay, but it still has nothing to do with your original question - it's raising the exception on the line: `with open(file) as f:`

Comment: hi @wpercy, I tightened it, and your solutions works. The only issue I have is that it seems to take a very long time to run. I have a slightly different solution below. But for some reason, the solution I post for my own question (!!!) runs a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @wpercy for his answer, which I cleaned up for below. However, it seems to take a very long time to run.

```
fileLoc ='T:\\Risk\\DataDump\\Trades_Test.txt'

with open(fileLoc) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]

for line in content:
    events = [line.split(' ') for line in content if ('2017-07-25' and 'CRDA') in line]
```

A slightly different way, but for some reason, it runs a lot faster. For reference, the file has more than 300k of lines.

```
file ='T:\\Risk\\Trades_Test.txt'


# this is to load the text file into content
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content] 

# this is to filter the lines in the data
events = []
for line in content:
    if (line.find('Action') >0 and line[0:10] == '2017-07-25') :
        events.append(line.split(' '))
    if (line.find('Allocation') >0 and line[0:10] == '2017-07-25'):
        events.append(line.split(' '))
```

Comment: it takes so long because you iterate over the lines in `content` three times when you only need to once...